# Angular 5 - router with two empty parent routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

This is a question to check if my thinking and implementation is correct.

I'm working on Angular app where I want to utilize two base layouts. Simple one, with header, content and footer. Second one extends simple layout with sidebars, permanent on the left, and slide sidebar on the right. In order to avoid lines of code to adjust the layout accordingly I thought that splitting them might be quicker, easier and would require less coding.

This is how I configured **routes.ts:**

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutSimpleComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
      { path: 'library', loadChildren: './library/library.module#LibraryModule' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
     ]
  },
   // Layout with sidebars
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutSidebarsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'products', loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsModule' },
      { path: 'forum', loadChildren: './forum/forum.module#ForumModule' }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
]
```

As you can see, both layout components use `path: ''` as a matcher so the actual routing depends on their children. **And it all works** I just have a strange feeling that this is not the best practice.

Are there any problems that might occur using this configuration? Is there better solution? So far I wasn't able to find anything about it.

Comment: I used this approach in a couple of places and there doesn't seem to be any problems so far.

Comment: I cannot see any downside beside readability. 
Perhaps something I have learned from Deborah Kurata would be also an option. 
https://youtu.be/LaIAHOSKHCQ?t=2m47s (from 2:47 till minute 5) Basically nesting two or multiple router-outlets.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look